# Groupwise sum based on criteria

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to figure out to calculate group wise sum for individual customer/subject and I need that sum to be in the first row of the corresponding customer.

[Data i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwRSl.png)

[image]

I need sum for each id where its cat="ote" and var = 181713. I tried sumifs function but it's aggregating sum for each row where my condition met.

[Data i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnY5y.png)

[image]

function i tried (=SUMIFS(F2:F31,A2:A31,A2,B2:B31,"ote",G2:G31,181713) )
I am doing something wrong over there. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying the formula down, you need absolute references for the ranges, like this, starting in row 2:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$31,$A$2:$A$31,A2,$B$2:$B$31,"ote",$G$2:$G$31,181713)
```

Copy that one down. Although it does not make sense to copy that formula down.

It would be much more logical to create a pivot table instead of using SumIfs().

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. Is it possible to get a single value in the new column instead of repetitive values? I agree that pivot is more sensible, but presently I need to figure it out using the function only.

Comment: Formulas are powerful, but they can't perform magic. I don't see why this scenario cannot be used in a pivot table. You can try to use formulas but it will be a lot more difficult. Why take the difficult route if there is an easy way?